# CGAL::assign function

Tags: cgal

everyone. I am new to CGAL library. Here I am reading a CGAL demo. The code uses CGAL::assign function quite often, but I cann't find any reference to it. Anyone can point it out where I can see the how it is implemented? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this: http://doc.cgal.org/4.2/CGAL.CGAL.STL-Extensions-for-CGAL/html/classCGAL_1_1Compact__container.html#aa00b4e0eea71edb800925e557f19e9da of any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CGAL::assign function

The doc is available here 
http://doc.cgal.org/4.2/CGAL.CGAL.STL-Extensions-for-CGAL/html/classCGAL_1_1Object.html